# Error when $.slider()'s parameter object's property references another property

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to create two handle slider using the following jQuery code :

```
      $( "#slider" ).slider({
          min : 0,
          max : 100,
          values : [ 20 , 80],
          slideLower : function(event, ui){
               $('#lower-cut-off').val( ui.values[0] + "%");
          },
          slide: function (event, ui) {
             slideLower(event, ui);
          }
      });
```

When I try to slide the handle, debugger shows there is a Reference Error thrown saying slideLower is undefined.

So my question is why can't I reference slideLower() from within slide() if they are both properties of the same object? Does this have something to do with how jQuery slider() processes the parameter object?

I tried making it `this.slideLower(event, ui)` but then I get

> TypeError: this.slideLower is not a function

I fixed it by inlining slideLower() within slide, but I still want to understand why the initial didn't work.

My hypothesis is that maybe slider() assigns the specified properties (like `max` `min` and `slide`) to another entity and ignores the rest. Is this what's going on or am I not using javascript scopes properly?

Comment: no... you can't access properties of an object as if they were globally defined... `this` also won't work if the function isn't executed with a context of the settings object. Best option here is to create a named function, and pass it to the `slideLower` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just because the function is stored in an object property doesn't mean it will be executed with the object as it's context. It's actually quite common for event handlers such as this to have the element the event was triggered on as the context instead.

that said, even if it was executed with the object as the context, `slideLower` still wouldn't be defined there, because it's a property of an object, and you would have to access it as such using `this.slideLower`. but, since that isn't the case, you really have no other option than defining the function with a name, and then passing it to the options object.

```
function slideHandler (event, ui){
    $('#lower-cut-off').val( ui.values[0] + "%");
}

$( "#slider" ).slider({
    min : 0,
    max : 100,
    values : [ 20 , 80],
    slideLower : slideHandler,
    slide: slideHandler
});
```